# how to set qTranslate for Wordpress to automatically give me German language although my website language is in English

Tags: wordpress, plugins, qtranslate

I installed qTranslate plugin (qtranslate-Version 2.8.42) for Wordpress.

My default language my website is written in English.

I have configured qTranslate plugin to show three languages on my website, i.e. German, English, and Chinese.

Nevertheless, I want my website to be in German instead of English on the first visit. I mean that although my website is in English I want it to show the German language first when somebody enters my website and NOT the original English language...

Is there any idea on how I could achieve this, please?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Dear Roy Thank you very much indeed for your kind help to correct my spelling and syntax! Much Appreciated! Costas.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not check the qTranslate's option page at Admin panel.

[image: Language order buttons]

See the marked area. The arrows are for setting the order of language. If you set German at top, it would be primarily selected.